# Did Xerox engineers really develop the first graphical user interface?

Tags: history, gui

Did the computer scientist at Xerox really develop the first graphical user interface, later showing this to both Steve Jobs and Bill Gates?

[Just for reference, it is in reference to this story.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J33pVRdxWbw)

Comment: Define the terminology … when OOP became a thing, the programming group I had been with for years discovered we had been designing and writing OO software on S/360 and S/370 for years, in Fortran. We didn't know somebody was going to invent a catchy name for it and turn into an buzzword - it just seemed like a good way to build big software systems. Of course the *syntax* got a bit prettier in other languages, but you can use OO in assembler if you want!

Comment: This question is way to wide to be answered in a serious way. Please specify what is exactly asked for (what is an Ian anyway?) and what are the qualifications to decide by.

Comment: @alephzero Damn, you just beat me in writing that :)) (Except we were using /370 Assembly :))

Comment: @Raffzahn to be fair, we had a few Assembly routines to do the equivalent of Unix "fork" and "exec" dynamically as well, so it wasn't 100% Fortran.

Comment: I'm going to VTC as too broad because I do not know which language OP had in mind

Comment: OKOK I remember the story wrong I was thinking of Xerox engineers not IBM, will edit.

Comment: Voting for a close. There seems to be at least three questions combined here... Please clarify question.

Comment: This whole question is far too broad. Ask about OOP, LAN and GUI separately please.

Comment: ok, I have posted the several questions like the mod required, get this reopened now, please.

Comment: @NeilMeyer Be patient! It's in the queue. Also, it's probably best to make this the GUI question and post the OOP question separately, seeing as this one already has a GUI answer.

Comment: @NeilMeyer Without explaining what language you refer to, or what criteria are to be used to define OOP in this context, the question can not be answered.

Comment: Ok i have made another  attempt at an edit.

Comment: In what way is the question too broad? It has a simple no answer. Voting to reopen.

Comment: The Byte magazine smalltalk issue mentions Simula and Flex as influences on page 36 so I'd say the answer was no (Wikipedia credits Simula as the first OOP language).

Comment: @Raffzahn An OOP language is one that has features to support the principles of object oriented programming, which are encapsulation, polymorphism, abstraction and inheritance. I think Simula is generally considered to be the first.

Comment: @JeremyP So, you say, all OOP languages come with all of this in full (what ever in full means)? There was (and is) no development from early stages (and no development since)? Serious? The simple **Answer will  of course be Assembler**. It can tick all the boxes mentioned. And it has done so.

Comment: @Raffzahn Assembler is clearly not object oriented - at least most common assemblers are not. Yes, you can always "roll your own" object oriented features in any Turing complete language but an OOP language has syntactical constructs designed specifically to support the OOP concepts even if the support is not perfect. For example C++ has poor encapsulation but is still considered object oriented.

Comment: @JeremyP Well, I guess now it's fair to state that you clearly never really worked with Assemblers - at least not in a serious setup. I's no big deal to use 'syntactical constructs' for OOP in Assembly - after all, it is the very feature of Assembly to be extensible. More important your remarks of 'not perfect' and 'still considered' hit exactly the point I made: without a specification what criteria the OP used to define first and OOP, the question is way too broad and can not be answered. There is not 'The OOP Language', there are languages with OOP features. Assembly being one of them :))

Comment: Proposed suggestion: someone should integrate the first version of the post to the current one on a way, that @alephzero 's answer already answers it, but it is not yet too broad (btw, if he could answer it, maybe it wasn't even *so* broad to be closed?). After that, rollback alephzero's last change. And everything will be happy.

Comment: @peterh I'm going to make that change and see who screams.

Comment: Not sure if that already has been mentioned, but if the OP just seeks background to the story, then yes, Xerox developed the [Alto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerox_Alto), which, if not the first with a GUI, probably was the first with a GUI solidly part of the OS, and yes, they showed to other people, including Steve Jobs and Bill Gates, and yes, it served as inspiration. And qualifications of "first" will ultimately need a definition (which is why I don't like questions about "what was the first X"; stuff tends to get invented gradually).

Comment: @JeremyP Poor encapsulation? Why? Well, maybe the private members can be made invisible with some trickery. I think ideally the protected members of a class should be completely invisible from outside. Do you think on that?

Comment: It's probably more accurate to say that Xerox invented the desktop metaphor. Graphical interfaces existed but were somewhat abstract, Xerox made something that mimicked the way people were already working.

Comment: @Raffzahn What syntactical constructs does MACRO-11 have to support inheritance?

Comment: @peterh Precisely, you need to do trickery. In C++ you can't even create a subclass without knowing the size of the class. That breaks encapsulation by itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect this is going to degenerate into an argument about what words mean, but back in 1965 the IBM 2250 graphics terminal had the equivalent of a mouse (actually a light pen) and a keypad with 32 clickable buttons that could be programmed to do anything (and have their functionality redefined depending on the context of what was being displayed on the screen).

Of course people wrote software for it that had a "graphical user interface" - though Xerox didn't invented the term until 1973, which is often considered the beginning of the concept of GUI.

It doesn't meet the OP's criterion though, because it was a commercial product that was actually sold to customers.

I doubt they showed the pre-release version to Steve Jobs, since he wouldn't have reached his 10th birthday at the time.

Comment: sorry i had the story wrong I was thinking of xerox engineers.

Comment: "Graphical user interface" probably means a WIMP application shell (desktop) and application support library in the context of this question. There certainly were user interfaces that were graphical before Xerox PARC built the Altos and the D machines, but I can't think of any predecessor to the Xerox machines that was WIMPy (unless,... maybe the original Lisp machines...?)

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The question asks specifically about the first Object Oriented Programming language, not the applications for which it might have been used.

Comment: Apologies. The question has been severely edited. Your answer *no longer* answers it.

Comment: Nice photo of the 2250 here https://collection.maas.museum/object/423702